# GedHTree - an excellent program to convert Gedcom to HTML- is no longer supported. How can I obtain a registration code?

Tags: gedcom, website

I'm looking for software that will convert my Gedcom to STATIC HTML files (no PHP) and display ancestor and descendant trees with at least 6 generations.

Up until about 10 years ago, there was a program called **GedHTree** which did exactly that and included various tree formats. Unfortunately, gedHTree has been discontinued and it's web site no longer exists. After an extensive search, I managed to download the last version of GedHTree (2.80) from some archive, but to get the results I want, I need a registered copy.

None of the registration links work. I tried locating the author, Gary Welker, but all of the email addresses I found, returned a failed status.

How I can register, locate the author or otherwise obtain a registered version of this software?

I've tried quite a few alternative software, but none give the simple results I'm looking for.

Comment: Are you using a particular OS (Mac, Windows, Linux,...) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although the site [www.gedhtree.com](http://www.gedhtree.com) is no longer there, the site [http://users.chariot.net.au/~ramacs/GedHTree/readme.htm](http://users.chariot.net.au/%7Eramacs/GedHTree/readme.htm) still exists that contains a lot of information about the program GedHTree.

The pages at the site were last updated in the year 2000, which is 20 years ago. The program was written for Windows 95/98 and the Fixes/Revisions page at the site has its last entry on Oct 9, 2000.

The readme page states that there are two methods for registering GedHTree.

1. By mail by sending $20 to the author Gary Welker in Longmont Colorado, or
2. By paying by credit card via DigiBuy which will send your registration code immediately via Email.

Method 1 is impossible because [Gary Welker passed away in 2015](https://www.dignitymemorial.com/obituaries/longmont-co/elmer-welker-9163284).

Method 2 is impossible because [the DigiBuy site closed in 2008](https://web.archive.org/web/20080325051128/http://www.digibuy.com/).

The website where those pages are hosted is the site of John Keynes. John still uses GedHTree for [his online family history site](http://users.chariot.net.au/%7Eramacs/). [John's home page](http://users.chariot.net.au/%7Eramacs/) does list his contact information, so you might want to try contacting him about the program.

Alternatively, you just might find a "cracked" version of GedHTree if you look, but I don't in any way condone the practice of supporting a crack site.

Personally, I would not want to use an unsupported 20 year old program no matter how good it was or still is. I would recommend you try [one of the hundred or so genealogy website generating programs currently available](https://www.gensoftreviews.com/index.php?type=web). Surely you'll find a few to be at least adequate but are still being developed by a developer who can provide you support for some years to come.

Comment: Normally I wouldn't use an unsupported program, but this case is different because it produces a set of static editable HTML files. So as long as there are no significant changes to the family tree, and as long as HTML continues to work on modern browsers, I can run the program once and the output files will continue to be relevant for many years.Anyway, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

I just found an old folder which had my registration written on the front.  About to throw the folder away, so here you go: 768254630

To register:

1. Run program, type in "gedhtree" in the file selected box.
2. Clear name fields - will change to register.
3. Enter first & last name, registration code.
4. Click "register" NOT "run."
5. After registration, click on the wash4.ged to clear registration fields.

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried this code on version 2.80 of gedHTree and it does not work. I get a message: "Registration was not successful..."